# how to identify hidden columns in excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am using Excel interop, to open a excel file and write data to the excel sheets. There are hidden columns in the excel sheet and its writing data to the hidden columns. How do I identify hidden columns and not write data in hidden columns ?

```
con.Open();           
string query1 =  "SELECT fi.* FROM ****",
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
// load the data set
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
// loop through the data set and write data to excel 
for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        String data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
        mWSheet1.Cells[i + 3, j + 1] = data;
    }
}
mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Missing.Value,
Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find out if there are hidden columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066200/find-out-if-there-are-hidden-columns-in-excel)

Comment: Add a check for the column.hidden property in your for loop.

Comment: Why are you using Excel Interop? Do you really need to interact with a running instance of Excel? Based on what you've described, you'd be better off with a library capable of directly manipulating Excel files without Interop, such as EPPlus, NPOI, Open XML SDK, Aspose, etc.

Comment: wait, are you using interop? it doesn't look like you are doing it right

Comment: `if (mWSheet1.Cells[i + 3, j + 1].EntireColumn.Hidden == true) ...`

Comment: doubling on what @mason said. No need for interop here. You can use `microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0` provider and connect to excel like to any other db. And there will be no hidden columns. all columns will be treated as table columns. Especially if this is server app, this is not good idea to use interop. There are plenty examples - google for it.